# SSIS creation of a csv file in every execution of my package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, msbi

My source is a database and my destination is a `*.csv` file, I want to create in every execution of my package a new `*.csv` file, so if I execute my package 3 times, I'll have 3 files for exemple : `1.csv`, `1(1).csv` and `1(2).csv` 
The name doesn't matter for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the filename does not matter, you can just generate one for example with

`select NEWID( )`

And store the id in a variable. Then assign this variable to the filename in your flat file connection manager.

See [Microsofts description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-2-3-modifying-the-flat-file-connection-manager?view=sql-server-ver15) how to do that.

Or one of many [youtube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F16zCo6OsgU)

If you want more control over the filename, a short script could check for existing files and set the next free filname into your variable.